# C counting number of numbers and letters from file

Tags: c, file

```
int main()
{

    // Defining that we only expect there to be a maximum of 1,000
    // characters per lines read.
    char buffer[1000];
    FILE *pFile;
    char numbers = 0;
    char chars = 0;

    // Opens the file for reading
    pFile = fopen("vstup.txt", "r");

    // fopen returns 1 if an error occurred 
    if (!pFile)
        printf("Error : Couldn't Read the File\n");


    while (fgets(buffer, 1000, pFile) != NULL)
    {

        printf("%s", buffer);

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i] >= '0' && buffer[i] <= '9')
            numbers++;

            if ((buffer[i] >= 'A' && buffer[i] <= 'Z') || (buffer[i] >= 'a' && buffer[i] <= 'z'))
                chars++;
        }

    }


    printf("\nSuccess Reading from File\n");
    printf("\nNum of numbers %d",numbers);
    printf("\nNum of letters %d", chars);

    // Closes the text file
    if (fclose(pFile) != 0)
        printf("Error : File Not Closed\n");

    getchar();

}
```

I am trying to count number of letters and numbers from file it works for numbers but it doesn’t work for letters and next think I am not sure how to right proceed for statement to not waste counts.

I will appreciative any help.

Comment: why *numbers* and *chars* counter are `char` type and not `integer` ?

Comment: Use `isalpha` and `isdigit` defined in `ctype.h`.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)` This loop assumes that each line has exactly 50 characters, but the lines probably can have any langth. Use `buffer[i] != '\0'` as condition.

Comment: ops my bad it should be int

Comment: By the way, in this case you can do away with reading lines (and therefore with guessing a maximum line length) by reading the input char by char with `fgetc`.

Comment: You count _digits_, not _numbers_.

Comment: BTW, it would be easier just to read a single character at a time with `fgetc`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx guys I did it with fgetc everything works now.

```
do
    {
        c = fgetc(pFile);
        if (feof(pFile))
        {
            break;
        }
        printf("%c", c);
        if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
            numbers++;

        if ((c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z'))
            chars++;
    } while (1);
```

Answer (score -1):

It's unlikely that this program will count anything accurately due to the fact that it's only checking 50 characters per line.

I'd suggest changing:

```
while (fgets(buffer, 1000, pFile) != NULL)
```

to:

```
for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer

Comment: Looks like an answer to me.

Comment: Your proposed change is for `for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)`, not `while (fgets(buffer, 1000, pFile) != NULL)`, and it is not correct, it should read `for (int i = 0; buffer[i] != '\0'; i++)`

Comment: oops!  copy & paste error, thanks.  maybe I should have my first coffee of the day before I submit my next answer :-P